# Deployment validation failed while creating Sendgrid account

Tags: azure-functions, sendgrid

i attempted to create a sendgrid account in **MS Azure Portal**, since i need to trigger a mail in Azure function app using blob trigger. While creating a sendgrid account i'm getting the following error

> Deployment validation failed.
>   Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'website' at line '85' and column '20' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.

[Error message appeared on portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq1hd.jpg)
i need to know why i'm getting this error,

i tried using both my work account and personal account still getting the same error, please help me to fix this issue

i tried with exiting resource group and created new resource group as well, both gives the same error

i tried with free plan and bronze plan, both gives the same error

Answer (score 4):

you are getting that error because you didnt provide a value for the parameter called `website`. You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy

I assume you are not doing this with the help of the portal, since portal wont allow to proceed if you didnt supply values for all the parameters

Comment: I used the Azure Portal only, i don't see any option like "website" and i didn't left out any mandatory options, i've added the screenshot of the message in my post now

Comment: can you share the template? this looks weird

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same issue recently and fixed it by creating the account on a resource group with the 'Azure for Students' subscription instead of 'Azure for Students Starter', then just putting whatever in the 'website' field, because if the field is left empty it will still return the same error despite [clearly showing that it isn't required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L43Zs.png).

If you try to fill in the website field (even with a legitimate entry) on a 'Azure for Students Starter' subscription [you'll get this error instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeSkx.png)